# Disable "Show position of the mouse when the Control key is pressed" in 13.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse

In version 12.10 there was a setting under System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad to "Show position of the mouse when the Control key is pressed”. While using 12.10 I enabled this option.

I have since upgraded to version 13.10, and this setting appears to have disappeared.

How can I now disable this? It is interfering with the use of the control key in a number of apps, such as VirtualBox.

I'm quite happy to use the terminal or edit a settings file if that is the best (only) way to do this. I really (!!) don't want to have to reinstall just to reset this one option.

Comment: Although 13.10 is still a development version the same problem exists under 13.04 (so the question is not off-topic). Try the solution by Seth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to use [gsettings - GSettings configuration tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/gsettings.1.html).

**1)** Open a terminal window to get the value of "locate-pointer" key.

- `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer`

If the result if "True" and you want to disable this feature type:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false`

**NOTE**: If you want to enable it, type:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true`

Or you can use dconf-tools to view and change the value.

**2)** To install dconf type:

- `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

**3)** Open dconf editor and navigate to the path org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse. "locate-pointer" key to change the value.

[image]

[image]